# SOAP XML only deserializing partially

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, soap, nullpointerexception

I am having a devil of a time getting some simple xml from a web service to deserialize properly. There are no errors when I actually deserialize, but the resulting object only goes a couple of nestings deep - once it reaches the "return" tag, both it and all children are null. I can't seem to figure out why it is failing at this point.. it seems the same as the other classes. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Sample XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <ns2:getPreSubmitInfoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.integration.someservice.com/">
     <return>
        <errorOccurred>false</errorOccurred>
        <message>Information returned successfully</message>
        <response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:webServicePO">
           <internalMessage>SUCCESS: Inventory Found</internalMessage>
           <poNum>56658</poNum>
           <residence>N</residence>
           <shipAddress1>TEST</shipAddress1>
           <shipAddress2 />
           <shipCity>TEST</shipCity>
           <shipMethod>UPS</shipMethod>
           <shipState>TX</shipState>
           <shipTo>TEST'S</shipTo>
           <shipZip>99999</shipZip>
           <webServicePoDetailList>
              <color>TEST</color>
              <errorOccured>false</errorOccured>
              <inventoryKey>TEST</inventoryKey>
              <message>Requested Quantity is confirmed and available in warehouse '2' to ship to your destination.</message>
              <quantity>5</quantity>
              <size>XS</size>
              <sizeIndex>1</sizeIndex>
              <style>TEST</style>
              <whseNo>2</whseNo>
           </webServicePoDetailList>
        </response>
     </return>
  </ns2:getPreSubmitInfoResponse>
```

C# classes:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "webServicePoDetailList")]
    public class WebServicePoDetailList
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "errorOccured")]
        public string ErrorOccured { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "inventoryKey")]
        public string InventoryKey { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "quantity")]
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "size")]
        public string Size { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "sizeIndex")]
        public string SizeIndex { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "style")]
        public string Style { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "whseNo")]
        public string WhseNo { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
    //[XmlInclude(typeof(webServicePO))]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "internalMessage")]
        public string InternalMessage { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "poNum")]
        public string PoNum { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "residence")]
        public string Residence { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipAddress1")]
        public string ShipAddress1 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipAddress2")]
        public string ShipAddress2 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipCity")]
        public string ShipCity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipMethod")]
        public string ShipMethod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipState")]
        public string ShipState { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipTo")]
        public string ShipTo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipZip")]
        public string ShipZip { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "webServicePoDetailList")]
        public WebServicePoDetailList WebServicePoDetailList { get; set; }
    }

    //[Serializable()] 
    //[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    //public class webServicePO : Response { }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "return")]
    public class Return
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "errorOccurred")]
        public string ErrorOccurred { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
        public Response Response { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "getPreSubmitInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://webservice.integration.someservice.com/")]
    public class GetPreSubmitInfoResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "return")]
        public Return Return { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "getPreSubmitInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://webservice.integration.someservice.com/")]
        public GetPreSubmitInfoResponse GetPreSubmitInfoResponse { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
```

You'll notice that I have tried to accommodate the xsi:type= declaration within response, but have had no success. I have also tried removing that declaration with the replace method, but nothing is working. When I originally converted this response to C# classes, all of the strings were defined as Elements, not Attributes, which I think was incorrect. I changed them, please let me know if that was a mistake (neither way works). I have also played around with the response namespace, but am not sure that has anything to do with my current error since the first null object in the chain is "return".

Comment: Even some insight into where the problem may lie would be helpful. If it is null for "return", does that mean the problem is within the "return" class or could it be one of it's children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse xml elements and xml attributes.

This set of classes is successfully deserializes the provided  xml.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    [XmlElement("getPreSubmitInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://webservice.integration.someservice.com/")]
    public GetPreSubmitInfoResponse GetPreSubmitInfoResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("getPreSubmitInfoResponse")]
public class GetPreSubmitInfoResponse
{
    [XmlElement("return", Namespace = "")]
    public Return Return { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("return")]
public class Return
{
    [XmlElement("errorOccurred")]
    public bool ErrorOccurred { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("response", Namespace = "")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(webServicePO))]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("internalMessage")]
    public string InternalMessage { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("poNum")]
    public ushort PoNum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("residence")]
    public string Residence { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipAddress1")]
    public string ShipAddress1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipAddress2")]
    public object ShipAddress2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipCity")]
    public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipMethod")]
    public string ShipMethod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipState")]
    public string ShipState { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipTo")]
    public string ShipTo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipZip")]
    public uint ShipZip { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("webServicePoDetailList")]
    public WebServicePoDetailList WebServicePoDetailList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("webServicePoDetailList", Namespace = "")]
public class WebServicePoDetailList
{
    [XmlElement("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("errorOccured")]
    public bool ErrorOccured { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("inventoryKey")]
    public string InventoryKey { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("quantity")]
    public byte Quantity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("sizeIndex")]
    public byte SizeIndex { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("style")]
    public string Style { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("whseNo")]
    public byte WhseNo { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("webServicePO", Namespace = "http://webservice.integration.someservice.com/")]
public class webServicePO : Response { }
```

Usage:

```
Envelope envelope;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(fs);

using (var fs = new FileStream("test2.xml", FileMode.Create))
    serializer.Serialize(fs, envelope);
```

After serialization will be obtain identical xml.

---

The only, I don't know how to change the name of the class `webServicePO` to `WebServicePO` - getting a lot of errors.

Comment: Thank you! I will take some time to analyze the differences.